# TeX capacity exceeded when using todo after itemize

Tags: errors, itemize, todonotes

I found that if you put a multi-line todo note underneath an itemize, I get an error. What could be the cause?

I am compiling with [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rtqcqhqsnbws), using pdfLaTex

Error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\par ->\@restorepar 
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty \everypar {}\par \@endpefalse 
l.13 inline}
```

[MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rtqcqhqsnbws):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item item
\end{itemize}
\todo[inline]{Two line 

inline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I adjusted your MWE so that it shows the error. As posted it had a blank line before the `\todo`  which avoids the error (and is the simplest answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs if the `\todo` follows immediately after the enviornment with no blank line (\par`) in between.

This modifies `\todo` so that if it detects latex's after display environment code (`\if@endpe` is true) it adds a `\par` automatically.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\let\oldtodo\todo
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\todo{%
\if@endpe\par\fi
\oldtodo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item item
\end{itemize}
\todo[inline]{Two line 

inline}

\end{document}
```

[image]